# Last child or last-type-of pseudo-class's not working, why?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I just set up a quick example of a issue I am having trouble with, right now I have some elements that have some styling added to them,  I have a class that I am try to apply a style to last child of that particular class. The issue I have is the last-child is not working when I have elements of any type after that class, here is my fiddle [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/7p9zq/1/) showing my issue, why wont my last-child or last-type-of work when the class is followed by other elements

Comment: From your demo i dont understand the effect you're looking for, are you looking to apply a different style to the last paragraph with a class of "test" on your page?

Comment: your markup is wrong BTW, you are using .blue and there's no class="blue" at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
p.test + *
{
    color:red;
    font-style:italic;
    font-size:40px;
}
p.test + p.test
{
    color:black;font-style:normal;font-size:inherit;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GCAf2/1/

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @BoltClock watch your jsfiddle, your markup is wrong: you are using .blue and there is no class="blue" at all in the provided markup

Comment: That should work, sorry for the mix up i meant to have .test for my class instead of blue in my fiddle I meant to update it

Comment: no problem! I've supposed your question.. ;) lol sorry Lawrence is not BoltClock